# Check if Object already exists in Collection - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am looking to add objects to a new collection as I loop through a series of different results.

The query:

```
$osRed = Item::where('category', 'Hardware')
        ->where(function ($query) {
            $query->where('operating_system', 'xxx')
                ->orWhere('operating_system', 'xxx')
                ->orWhere('operating_system', 'xxx');
        })
        ->orderBy('operating_system', 'ASC')
        ->get();
```

Then, loop through these results and add related objects to a new collection.

```
foreach ($osRed as $os) {
        foreach ($os->services as $service) {
            if (!($servicesImpacted->contains($service))) {
                $servicesImpacted->push($service);
            }
        }
}
```

I then go on to another set of results and add the related services from those results to the collection.

However, it is not picking up that the object is already in the collection and I end up with a large number of (what appear to be) duplicates.

Ideally, I would like to match up on the name attribute of the $service object, but that doesn't seem to be supported by the contains method.

```
toString() must not throw an exception
```

Comment: Can you provide your models and relations what you defined? It seems, that you can write something like that: Item::where(...)->with('services');

Comment: So `$servicesImpacted` is a collection of objects. right?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

You can use [`contains()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-contains) with key and value defined:

```
if (!$servicesImpacted->contains('name', $service->name))
```

Or you could use [`where()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-where) and [`count()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-count) collection methods in this case, for example:

```
if ($servicesImpacted->where('name', $service->name)->count() === 0)
```

Comment: Thanks @Alexey  Was still getting toString error with the `count() approach.  However, you helped me fix the issue with the contains method and it is working a treat now :)

Comment: How come https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-collections#method-contains does not illustrate the same form of params used here? I'm confused.

Answer (score 17):

You can use the contains() method in Laravel for
Check some specific key of value exists or not.
If value available in the collection for the specific key then returns true.

```
if($collection->contains('product_id',1234))
{
  echo "product id 1234 available in collection";
}
```